# Docker clamav AWS lambda layer build on mac M1

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, clamav

Attempting to run the docker file from here

https://dev.to/sutt0n/using-a-lambda-container-to-scan-files-with-clamav-via-serverless-2a5g

I get an error

> => ERROR [10/52] RUN yumdownloader -x *i686 --archlist=x86_64 clamav

```
#13 4.564 64 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
#13 4.623 No Match for argument clamav
#13 4.623 Nothing to download
```

I am guessing that I need the i686 binary to run on AWS. How to get this to work?

Epel is installed

```
 => CACHED [ 9/54] RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [10/54] RUN yum install -y epel-release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3.4s
 => [11/54] RUN yum install -y cpio yum-utils tar.x86_64 gzip zip
```

I started the docker container and login

> docker exec -it 31a81f061b7e bash

Editing cat /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf  does nothing.

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
213 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

repo id                 repo name                         status
amzn2-core/2/aarch64    Amazon Linux 2 core repository    19985
amzn2extra-epel/2/aarch64  Amazon Extras repo for epel    1 
epel/aarch64             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - aarch64       12775+213
```

repolist: 32761

Shows ARM architecture.

```
 # yum search clamav
 Loaded plugins: ovl
 === N/S matched: clamav ========
clamav-filesystem.noarch : Filesystem structure for clamav
clamav-unofficial-sigs.noarch : Scripts to download unofficial clamav signatures
clamav.aarch64 : End-user tools for the Clam Antivirus scanner
clamav-data.noarch : Virus signature data for the Clam Antivirus scanner.
clamav-devel.aarch64 : Header files and libraries for the Clam Antivirus scanner
 clamav-lib.aarch64 : Dynamic libraries for the Clam Antivirus scanner
clamav-milter.aarch64 : Milter module for the Clam Antivirus scanner
clamav-update.aarch64 : Auto-updater for the Clam Antivirus scanner data-files
```

Probably *clamav.aarch64*.

Take a guess, edit the Dockerfile. Sadly no.

```
 ERROR [11/53] RUN yumdownloader -x *i686 --archlist=x86_64 clamav.x86_64
```

Comment: What kind of ERROR? An errors is always accompanied by some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hunch regarding platform seems to have been correct. Take Sutton's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sutt0n/serverless-clamav-lambda-layer/blob/lambda-image/Dockerfile) and specify a platform. Randomly chose 'amd64' as opposed to x86-64 which seems more logical as per [a derivative blog post](https://instil.co/blog/scanning-files-with-clamav-and-cdk/)

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2

WORKDIR /home/build

RUN set -e
```